# Does the Term “Release” Carry Positive or Negative Connotations in Employment Termination?

Tags: termination, terminology

In a workplace communication, if a external contractor is described as being “released” on a specified date with the option for an earlier release, and a change order is to be issued to document this updated end date does this at least say that the client is willing to keep the person around because they still find them valuable?

Answer (score 4):

> Does the Term “Release” Carry Positive or Negative Connotations in Employment Termination?

It is neither negative nor positive.

It is just a standard term to say that you no longer work for the company.

It could mean that you quit your current job on your own free will (maybe to get a better job elsewhere, to retire, or to change your career). Or, it could mean that you are laid off or fired.

Comment: But if you have the opportunity to ask the reason, should you or just let it go and move on?

Comment: Yes, for sure, you can ask for the reason or explanation. Usually, they should at least tell you in person the reason/explanation. But, the term "release" does not imply anything negative or positive.

Comment: But if I was told by email that I should not directly ask the manager about the reasons why, could I get into legal trouble if I do ask them?

Comment: We don't know either

Answer (score 1):

> does this at least say that the client is willing to keep the person around because they still find them valuable?

Technically, to a certain extent, it does.

But I don't think you should read too much into it. Maybe they're panicking because the person in charge is on vacation. Or maybe they're panicking because they're not sure your knowledge has been transferred yet.

There could be a thousand and one reasons why they want to keep you around for a little longer. If you really want to know, you should ask the client company.

The term "release" itself has no positive or negative connotations.

Answer (score 1):

> In a workplace communication, if a external contractor is described as
> being “released” on a specified date with the option for an earlier
> release, and a change order is to be issued to document this updated
> end date does this at least say that the client is willing to keep the
> person around because they still find them valuable?

When I read this question I am interpreting it differently.

There exists a contract between company and a contractor. That contract has an expiration date. That means once that date hits either there is no relationship going forward, or a new contract needs to be negotiated and put into action.

> with the option for an earlier
> release, and a change order is to be issued to document this updated
> end date.

Now there is a desire to end the contract earlier.  There is a contract mod to terminate the contract early.

The question is why? Poor performance? The company no longer needs that specific service? The company is running out of money?

How this contract modification is made, and if the company owes a early termination fee depends on the terms of the original contract.

> does this at least say that the client is willing to keep the
> person around because they still find them valuable?

It doesn't tell us they wanted to keep the service. The company wants to end the contract early. why? only the company and the contractor know the answer.

Of course (as was pointed out in a comment) the reverse of all this could be true. The company could have been fired by the contractor.

Comment: The opposite could also have been true: the contractor wanted to be released from the contract earlier, and the company agreed.

Comment: good point..I will add that to the answer.